# how do i get an element that had its state changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a situation where once I click an image, I'd like it to get a border.  And if i click it again, i'd like that border to be removed.  BUT, i also want that border to be removed (or "moved") if another image is clicked instead!

i guess there are a couple of ways to go about this - both of which im not sure how to implement:

1. clear out all of the images' borders
2. keep track of previous state and get the element that way

im using states that are passed down from like great-grandparents, so not sure i can post all the scripts - ill try to keep it in snippets instead.

**my images: using 'next/image'**

```
    return(
        <div key={attr} id={attrprops.attrChoice+':'+attr}>
        <Image
            src={imgSourceUrl}
            alt={attrprops.alt}
            width={attrprops.w}
            height={attrprops.h}

            onClick={()=>{  attrprops.setButtonClick(!attrprops.buttonClick);
                            attrprops.setBorder(attrprops.selectedAttr==attr ? false : true);
                            attrprops.setSelectedAttr(attr);
                        }}
        />
        <br></br>
        <div className='flex justify-center align-center'>{attr}</div>
        </div>
    );
```

**my state change:**

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if (border&&buttonClick){
        document.getElementById(`body_type:${selectedAttr}`).className = 'border-2 border-blue-500';
        publishprops.setAttrNumber(4);
    }
    else if (!border&&buttonClick){
        document.getElementById(`body_type:${selectedAttr}`).className = 'border:none';
        publishprops.setAttrNumber(2);
    }
},[border])
```

the way it is currently, it only adds the borders to selected images. really not sure what route to go on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use React effectively, you need to change your thinking about the state a little. Your template should read easily, it should be clear what's the intent.

It looks like your example is pretty simple. It's either some image highlighted, or none.

Consider this simplified example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const images = [
    '1.png',
    '2.png',
    '3.png',
    '4.png',
    '5.png',
];

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);

    return (
        <ul>
            {images.map(src => (
                <img
                    key={src}
                    className={`
                        my-image
                        ${selectedImage === src ? 'active' : ''}
                    `}
                    onClick={() => setSelectedImage(
                        selectedImage => (
                            selectedImage !== src
                            ? src
                            : null
                        )
                    )}
                />
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
};
```

When `selectedImage` is `null` it means that no image has been clicked. And on click, we're either setting it to the clicked image, or setting it back to `null` if the same image has been clicked. And then you'd apply the border to images with `active` class. Simplified CSS:

```css
.my-image {
    border: 5px solid transparent;
}

.my-image.active {
    border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for taking the time! i am taking your advice and keeping the state simple by using just one - but is there a way to implement the css change with state - instead of active/nonactive? for example with a useeffect?

Comment: But why? You shouldn't reference DOM elements when it's not absolutely necessary. You can set the style inline if that works better for you: `style={{border-width: '5px', borderStyle: 'solid', borderColor: selectedImage === src ? 'red' : 'transparent'}}`

Comment: ahh i see. i figured i have to use state because depending on the image, the api will adjust, so why not throw css into it- also i have no idea about css and get things like this ```Syntax error: Selector "img" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)```

Comment: Yeah, that's the error next.js gives. Just add another class to the image. I'll update the answer.

Comment: i was playing around with it, and ```.my-image.active``` doesn't work but ```.my-image:active``` does HOWEVER, it only works until you let go of the click :/

Comment: Because `:active` is a pseudoclass and it's not what you want. `.my-image.active` means that both class names are applied together. If you used my code, then it will work.

Comment: could it be because im using ```<Image>``` from next.js instead of ```<img>``` and have the class name in a div outside of that tag, because next doesn't allow it inside?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Can you do a quick CSS course of the basics?

Comment: ok, so it seems because i was using css modules, interpolation wasnt working... i ended up with ```className={
                                                                            selectedAttr === attr ? styleBodytype.body_type_active : styleBodytype.body_type 
                                                                        }>``` thanks for your help!